# Audio Driver not Found Issue in Manjaro Linux

Tags: audio, drivers, operating-systems, manjaro

I need Help in resolving the Audio Card not found issue in the Manjaro Operating system.

When I installed the Manjaro Operating system the Audio driver was uninstalled and Now that driver is not at all detecting.

Please help me this issue. It will be very great full for me if you can.